# What tag does one use to make page hooks in XHTML?

Tags: html, hook

I need to make a "go to top" button. I've made it, with an Top but I forgot what tag I should use to make the hook. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the anchor tag:

```
<a href="#page">top</a>
```

Where page is the id property of some tag near the top:

```
<div id='page'>
  .
  .
  .
</div>
```

Or any tag you like.

Comment: Thank you very much. Oh one more thing, do I need to close it or do I leave it just like that?

Comment: Close what? Anchor tags always need an end tag to conform to XHTML. Like the div.

Comment: You need to close it, so it's like `<div id='page'>some text here</div>`